# What can i use as a device identifier in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm building an app and I need a unique identifier for each device and I don't want it to change even if the user uninstalls the app, what should I use? I don't know what I should look for. I searched a bit and I found something named *deviceid* is it good enough?
https://pub.dev/packages/device_id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently device_id plugin have some bugs with newest versions of flutter. You can use [device_info](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info) instead.
Here is an example:

```
 static Future<List<String>> getDeviceDetails() async {
  String deviceName;
  String deviceVersion;
  String identifier;
  final DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfoPlugin = new DeviceInfoPlugin();
  try {
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    var build = await deviceInfoPlugin.androidInfo;
    deviceName = build.model;
    deviceVersion = build.version.toString();
    identifier = build.androidId;  //UUID for Android
  } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
    var data = await deviceInfoPlugin.iosInfo;
    deviceName = data.name;
    deviceVersion = data.systemVersion;
    identifier = data.identifierForVendor;  //UUID for iOS
  }
} on PlatformException {
  print('Failed to get platform version');
}

//if (!mounted) return;
return [deviceName, deviceVersion, identifier];
}
```

Comment: identifier = data.identifierForVendor;  //UUID for iOS will change on application reinstall.
Read the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor)

Answer (score 3):

The safest way is to build a registration for the user. So, if the user want to use your app, he needs to register a profile. Each account gets a unique identifier and even when the user reinstall the app you can identifier him.

The package that you linked is possible too, but remember jailbreaked devices could change the device id.

I'm not 100% sure, but in Swift/iOS you can use for this case KeyChain. Check [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage), maybe it can help you. You can find more infos about KeyChain [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH203-TP1).